# Get correct time difference between two times

Tags: mysql

I have requirement to get the time difference between two times(24-hours format).Sum all find difference and minus to allocated weekly hours.

For finding difference between two time(start_time and end_time). I have used mysql query:

```
 SELECT es.empid,es.shiftid, es.start_time,es.end_time,TIMEDIFF(es.end_time, es.start_time) FROM 
`empschedule` AS es INNER JOIN `employee` AS e ON  es.`empId`=e.`empID`
```

**Query Result:**

[image]

For first two records i found correct difference but for last record i got wrong difference.please help me how i get correct difference.

Comment: why this diff is incorrect? `8-23 = -15`

Comment: Presumably 8 is the next morning, so the answer should be 9 hours

Comment: The usual way of dealing with this is to detect when the hours clocked crosses midnight, and to add 24 hours to the out time, so in this case the worker would be clocked in from 23:00 to 32:00. 32-23 then gives 9 hours. You may also need to handle daylight saving changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose OP looks for:

```
select
    es.empid,
    es.shiftid,
    es.start_time,
    es.end_time,
    case when (es.end_time > es.start_time) then
        timediff(es.end_time, es.start_time)
    else
        ADDTIME(timediff('24:00:00', es.start_time), es.end_time)
    end
FROM `empschedule` AS es
INNER JOIN `employee` AS e
ON  es.`empId`=e.`empID`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with ABS() function

```
SELECT es.empid,es.shiftid, es.start_time,es.end_time,ABS(TIMEDIFF(es.end_time, es.start_time)) FROM 
`empschedule` AS es INNER JOIN `employee` AS e ON  es.`empId`=e.`empID`
```